# Where can I find a schema of wordpress plugin core architecture?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, settings-api

There are plenty of articles which explain how to create a wordpress plugin. I'm not looking for that, I'm looking for a schema of the core architecture of a wordpress plugin (an UML class diagram and sequence for example).

Has somebody seen anything like that somewhere ?

Update: I know plugin can be as simple as a function. It's not my question. My question is about the architecture of the CALLER that calls the plugin, that is the architecture of the SYSTEM pertaining to the call of the plugin.

At least in which PHP module(s) is it implemented by the Wordpress Core System files ?

Comment: Now I might be mistaken, but the majority of Wordpress plugins are not very object-structured. So UML diagrams could be difficult to find. -- Btw, you could consider flagging your question for moderator attention to have it moved to http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: OK you're right I'll flag to request the move.

Comment: You are not looking for architecture but for designs. Architect <> Designer. Architecture is on meta level e.g. http://www.togaf.info/togaf9/togafSlides9/TOGAF-V9-M7-Metamodel.pdf designing is e.g. uml / logical data models /operational models.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is not much to it, really.

1. During the loading of WordPress engine `wp-settings.php` file is processed.
2. Among other things this files calls `wp_get_active_and_valid_plugins()` function, that gets list of activated (through admin interface) plugins from `active_plugins` option (stored in database).
3. For each active plugin its main file (the one holding plugin header) is `include`d and from there it is up to plugin how it uses Plugins API (more commonly known as hooks) to integrate with WordPress.

Basically it is only a thin layer of active/inactive controls on top of straight PHP `include`.

Comment: OK thanks it's a good start for me to look for in the right place :)

Comment: I found ref here http://phpxref.ftwr.co.uk/wordpress/nav.html?_functions/index.html and here http://www.phpxref.com/xref/wordpress/_functions/wp_get_active_and_valid_plugins.html

Comment: @user310291 only be careful that third party xrefs can be of outdated WP versions. It's not cross-referenced but you can explore code in official subversion repository via trac http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.1

Comment: the official site doesn't seem as practical: how can I get all "Functions defined on the site" like on phpxref ?

Comment: @user310291 in which context and for which purpose? You can always generate your own xref. Or retrieve this via PHP code. Or use IDE with such functionality. Also see my [Codex Generator](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/codex-generator/) plugin that gives you interface to explore active functions.

Answer (score 5):

The WP plugin architecture is event based and is very simple:

Events are attached using `add_action()` and `add_filter()`.

Events are triggered using `do_action()` and `apply_filters()`.

All these functions are found in `wp-includes/plugin.php`

More information can be found here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API

For a "flow diagram" of sorts, see this site: http://wp-roadmap.com/demo/

Comment: Once again I'm not looking for How to create a plugin, I'm looking for the architecture of the ENGINE. Like I'm not asking about how to assemble a PC, I'm asking about the architecture of the Processor.

Comment: OOP can be and mostly is Event Based since it's non-linear programming. But that is not the problem, architecture schema can be done OOP or not OOP.

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: Related answer: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/12576/how-does-wordpress-uninclude-deactivate-a-plugin/12583#12583